# What is the name of this theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Let  $f: G\to K$ a morphism of groups. If $H\subset \ker f$, then there existe a  unique morphism of groups $g : G/H\to K$ such that  $f=gs$. Moreover,

$g$ is surjective if $f$ is surjective ;

$g$ is injective if we have $H=\ker f$ ;

$g$ in an isomorphism if $f$ is surjetive and $H=\ker f$

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_factorisation#Le_cas_des_groupes

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to call this the 1st isomorphism theorem of groups, although that is usually stated in the weaker form $G/\ker{f}\cong\operatorname{im}(f)$ (with $f$ as in your question).

To a degree I think the theorem you state is what should *really* be called the 1st isomorphism theorem, and I doubt it's different enough from what is usually called the 1st isomorphism theorem to have a new name.

Comment: but in the 1st isomorphism theorem of groups we have $f:G\rightarrow G'$ here $K$ is a ring !

Comment: in french in wiki they cald it factorisation theorem

Comment: You didn't say that... And I don't think your link does either (my French isn't great, but I don't see "anneau" anywhere). Besides, if $G$ is a group then as far as the morphism is concerned $K$ is only a group (the underlying additive group of the ring) as well. If it's called the factorization theorem in French then probably that will do in English as well.

Comment: Reading a little more, it seems that the factorization theorem is the name for the general categorical theorem that generalizes the 1st isomorphism theorems for groups, rings, modules etc.